# Find file/folders containing a string and remove but exclude a string from being removed

Tags: linux, bash

The questions says it all really (Find file/folders containing a string and remove but exclude a string from being removed). Here is what I have came up with so far but it doesn't seem to work (please note I am aware that the line doesn't delete).

```
grep -l "music_file" * | grep -v "music_file_new"
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question, in your example it looks like you're trying to find all the lines that contain the string "music_file" but not those that contain "music_file_new".  What is it that you want to do instead?  Perhaps an example with input and desired output would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use grep and you suspect there will be collisions in your patterns, as in your example, then you want to use grep's "-w" flag to select the pattern as if it were a complete word.